# How to cross-domain transfer data from parent page DOM to iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, extract, postmessage

I need to transfer a large amount of data cross-domain from the parent page into an iframe. The data will be a long list of user contact information (for example, a thousand names and email addresses) and will usually be in some kind of list form in the DOM. The data needs to be extracted from the html on the parent page and then passed to the iframe. It appears postMessage is the way to do this but I am looking for implementation suggestions on how to do this efficiently as performance is key. The solution must also be flexible as the structure of the data on the parent page may vary.

Comment: So you're looking for a [postMessage tutorial?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) Your question is extremely unspecific.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to make this work you will need access to the source code of both pages (the source page to send the message and the target page to *explicitly* receive it).